# Magento 2.3.4 not installed in windows, wamp server shows 500 internal server error

Tags: magento2.3.4

MAgento 2.3.4 not installed in windows, wamp server shows 500 internal server error

**wamp server details**

Apache/2.4.23 (Win64)

PHP/7.3.14 Server at 127.0.0.1 Port 82

Comment: remove code under if conditions from .htaccess files in magento root and other folders

Comment: Magento officially does not support windows, so i would suggest installing linux and running Magento there.